# SQL Left(column,6) function - What am i doing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

so i have this query

```
Select Distinct                 
    ACCT.Account , ACCT_SUMM.TotalTrades,ACCT_SUMM.TotalRev, ACCT_SUMM.US_Options, ACCT_SUMM.CAD_Options, ACCT_SUMM.USStock, ACCT_SUMM.CADStock, ACCT.ACCT_OPEN_DATE, ACCT_SUMM.ACCTYPE,                                                                    
        CASE                
           WHEN Min(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(ACCT_OPEN_DATE)) <= 1              THEN 'New_Accounts'   
           WHEN Min(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(ACCT_OPEN_DATE)) > 1  THEN 'Old_Account'             

        END as 'ClientAgeSeg'   



        From [dbo].[WF_PM_ACCT_DB] ACCT 
        Join (          
                    Select Distinct Account, Sum(DB_12) as 'TotalTrades',Sum(DB_3) as 'TotalRev', Sum(DB_12_1_6) as 'US_Options', Sum(DB_12_1_5) as 'CAD_Options', Sum(DB_12_5) as 'USStock',Sum(DB_12_4) as 'CADStock',
                            CASE 
                                WHEN SUM(DB_12) = 0 THEN 'INACTIVE'
                                WHEN SUM(DB_12) > 0 and SUM(DB_12) <=119  and Sum(DB_12_1_6) = 0 and Sum(DB_12_1_5) = 0   THEN 'Engaged Stock Pure'
                                WHEN SUM(DB_12) > 119  and Sum(DB_12_1_6) = 0 and Sum(DB_12_1_5) = 0   THEN 'Active Stock Pure'
                                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) > 120 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) > 120) And (SUM(DB_12_4)<=0  and SUM(DB_12_5)<=0)   THEN ' Pure Active OPT'
                                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) <= 119 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) <= 119) And (SUM(DB_12_4)<=0  And SUM(DB_12_5)<=0) THEN 'Pure Engaged OPT'
                                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) > 120 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) > 120) And (SUM(DB_12_4)>0  or SUM(DB_12_5)>0)   THEN 'Mix Active OPT'
                                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) <= 119 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) <= 119) And (SUM(DB_12_4)>0  or SUM(DB_12_5)>0)   THEN 'Mix Engaged OPT'

                                Else 'Unclassified'

                            END as 'ACCTYPE'
                    FROM WEALTHDB.DBO.WF_PM_SUM_DB
                    Group by Account

                    ) ACCT_SUMM
        On ACCT.Account = ACCT_SUMM.Account 
        Group by ACCT.Account, ACCT_SUMM.TotalTrades, ACCT_SUMM.US_Options, ACCT_SUMM.CAD_Options, ACCT_SUMM.USStock, ACCT_SUMM.CADStock, ACCT.ACCT_OPEN_DATE, ACCT_SUMM.TotalRev, ACCT_SUMM.ACCTYPE
```

I have just realized that i need to select the distinct accounts but only the first 6 letters. This code is selecting information from 2 different tables and from both i need to look at only the first 6 letters group by that and then display the results. I have tried a few things like select distinct left(account,6) as accountt but i get an invalid column name error with any combination that i try. What am i missing

I use microsoft managment studio 2012 and the sql server itself is 2000

Comment: There isn't even one `Left(...)` call in your sql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select              
    ACCT_SUMM.Account, ACCT_SUMM.TotalTrades,ACCT_SUMM.TotalRev, ACCT_SUMM.US_Options, ACCT_SUMM.CAD_Options, ACCT_SUMM.USStock, ACCT_SUMM.CADStock, ACCT.ACCT_OPEN_DATE, ACCT_SUMM.ACCTYPE,                                                                    
        CASE                
           WHEN Min(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(ACCT_OPEN_DATE)) <= 1 THEN 'New_Accounts'   
           WHEN Min(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(ACCT_OPEN_DATE)) > 1  THEN 'Old_Account'             
        END as 'ClientAgeSeg'   
From [dbo].[WF_PM_ACCT_DB] ACCT 
    Join (          
    Select LEFT(Account,6) AS Account, Sum(DB_12) as 'TotalTrades',Sum(DB_3) as 'TotalRev', Sum(DB_12_1_6) as 'US_Options', Sum(DB_12_1_5) as 'CAD_Options', Sum(DB_12_5) as 'USStock',Sum(DB_12_4) as 'CADStock',
            CASE 
                WHEN SUM(DB_12) = 0 THEN 'INACTIVE'
                WHEN SUM(DB_12) > 0 and SUM(DB_12) <=119  and Sum(DB_12_1_6) = 0 and Sum(DB_12_1_5) = 0   THEN 'Engaged Stock Pure'
                WHEN SUM(DB_12) > 119  and Sum(DB_12_1_6) = 0 and Sum(DB_12_1_5) = 0   THEN 'Active Stock Pure'
                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) > 120 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) > 120) And (SUM(DB_12_4)<=0  and SUM(DB_12_5)<=0)   THEN ' Pure Active OPT'
                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) <= 119 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) <= 119) And (SUM(DB_12_4)<=0  And SUM(DB_12_5)<=0) THEN 'Pure Engaged OPT'
                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) > 120 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) > 120) And (SUM(DB_12_4)>0  or SUM(DB_12_5)>0)   THEN 'Mix Active OPT'
                WHEN (Sum(DB_12_1_6) <= 119 OR Sum(DB_12_1_5) <= 119) And (SUM(DB_12_4)>0  or SUM(DB_12_5)>0)   THEN 'Mix Engaged OPT'
                Else 'Unclassified'
            END as 'ACCTYPE'
    FROM WEALTHDB.DBO.WF_PM_SUM_DB
    Group by LEFT(Account,6)
    ) ACCT_SUMM
    On LEFT(ACCT.Account,6) = ACCT_SUMM.Account 
Group by ACCT_SUMM.Account, ACCT_SUMM.TotalTrades, ACCT_SUMM.US_Options, ACCT_SUMM.CAD_Options, ACCT_SUMM.USStock, ACCT_SUMM.CADStock, ACCT.ACCT_OPEN_DATE, ACCT_SUMM.TotalRev, ACCT_SUMM.ACCTYPE
```

Comment: That worked. Any idea how i can only view the accounts that were tagged as New_Accounts?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you lose the column name when you use functions like [`LEFT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx). The result of your join needs a column name for account. So like in DVT's answer, you should use `LEFT(Account,6) AS Account`.

This will allow you to `SELECT ACCT_SUMM.Account` from the join.